# Question on hold versus closed

Tags: discussion

I have a question about my Health Stack Exchange post: [Based on facts (not opinion), are bran flakes healthier than shredded wheat?](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/15398/based-on-facts-not-opinion-are-bran-flakes-healthier-than-shredded-wheat)

My question had a notice saying that it was on hold, but a commentor said that he closed it.  What is the difference between these two states, and which is in effect?

The on-hold notice said to modify it for clarity, so I editted it to meet the issues raised by both the on-hold notice and the commentor who supposedly closed it.  What do I now have to do to have it possibly un-held or un-closed?  Would the actions required of me be different depending on which of the two states that my question is in?

The suggestions to edit the question was on the on-hold notice. If instead, it was closed, would anyone actually get notification that it was editted and hence subject to review to be made un-closed?

Answer (score 3):

On hold/Closed are essentially the same thing. A question is "on hold" for the first 5 days, and any edits make it automatically appear in the "reopen" review queue. After 5 days it changes to a Closed status.

Relevant Stack meta post: [What is a "closed", “on hold”, or "duplicate" question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-on-hold-or-duplicate-question)

You have edited your title, but not your question. Your basic question is:

"Based on that alone, I'm inclined to believe that my friends are right, and that I should switch to shredded wheat. Does reasoning seem sound?"

Which is still asking for a personal decision, which is off topic. If you would like it to have a better chance of reopening, ***all*** personal reference needs to be removed.

Comment: OK, thanks for clarifying.  I've articulated the question with less references to people's beliefs (other than my own).  I describe the challenges for me to assess the information.  Hopefully, it is now acceptable.  If not, thanks for pointing out where else it can be shored up, assuming that it is salvagable.  If it is beyond rescue, due to some fundamental aspect of the question, better to let me know.